# Tracker.Current.Session.Identify error :The given key was not present in the dictionary

Tags: xdb, contact-facets, tracking

In my Sitecore application, I've created custom facet (it has simple fields and object lists). I identify the user by the method:

```
  try
  {
    if (Tracker.IsActive)
    {
      Tracker.Current.Session.Identify(userId);
      Tracker.Current.Contact.ContactSaveMode = Analytics.Model.ContactSaveMode.AlwaysSave;
    }
  }
```

Sometimes, when it is called, an error occurs:

> ERROR The given key was not present in the dictionary. RROR    at
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Model.Framework.ModelUtilities.CopyElement(IElement
>   source, IElement destination)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.MergeContacts.MergeContactFacets.Process(MergeContactArgs
>   args)    at (Object , Object[] )    at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)    at
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName,
>   PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.MergeContacts.MergeContactPipeline.Run(MergeContactArgs
>   args)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Data.ContactRepository.MergeContacts(Contact
>   survivingContact, Contact dyingContact)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.StandardSession.Identify(String userName)

Do you know what this is caused by? The facet is added in the configuration and the data is put away (they are used in xDB conditions)

Comment: Can you find the contact with your userId in mongo (e.g. using robomongo) and see all its facets? It looks like during the merge, whatever is there in the  source cannot be copied to the target. Do you use your mongo for multiple instances?

Comment: Contact exist in mongoDB. I have one instance of mongo, but application have one CM and two CD.

Comment: Do you have the same facets on both CM and CD?

Comment: User identification is only on CD servers, but configured in config files are here and here. CD and CM use the same mongoDB database

Comment: Sitecore version?

Comment: Sitecore version is 8,2